# When importing, why does SQLite add quotes to my data

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

I am importing a .csv file with the current format being

```
car|"city"|price|dealer
camry|"oakland"|20000|""
accord|"richmond"|20000|""
```

and when I import from linux using

```
.mode ascii
.separator | \n
```

The data in the table has quotes added to it and looks like:

```
"car|""city""|"price"|"dealer""
"camry|""oakland""|20000|""""
"accord|""richmond""|20000|""""
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Edit: I tried .mode csv initially but I got an error saying " is an unescaped character.

Comment: You want `.mode csv`

Comment: @Shawn I initially tried with .mode csv  I got an error saying " is an unescaped character.

Comment: Works fine for me with your sample data and `.sep |`. The quotes are removed like they should be.

Comment: Did it work for you with .mode csv or .mode ascii. thanks

Comment: With `.mode csv`. Quotes are just another character in ascii mode (Which uses ASCII US and RS bytes by default so is an unusual choice to see anyone trying to use)

Comment: Figured it out, thanks